# Kinect colored object localization (detection)

Tags: localization, navigation, kinect, tabletop-object-detector, object-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all dear friends,

I am new in ROS and Kinect, and I want to DETECT a COLORED OBJECT (i.e a res sphere), I need it's POSITION (x, y, z) but not in image (CMVISION does this already), I tried to see all the previous questions but I did not find my answer and also I read the tutorial I tried to use RGBD_SLAM, VISION_VISP ... but I had problem with them..

Any body had same experience? any short message also could help me a lot.

Thank you
Hamed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128886/kinect-colored-object-localization-(detection)/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With depth registration turned on, you can use cmvision to detect an object in the RGB image, and then use the pixel coordinates to lookup the (x,y,z) position in the point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-13**:
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-19**:
I used the CMVISION, and it workes perfectly, but still I have problem to transfer the image coordinates to world coordinates.... as you told me I should use PIXEL COORDINATES.... but I am really new in PCL, if you had already done this, can you give me some hints?

THanks you in advance...